# WCF SQL insert GUID conversion error

Tags: c#, .net

I am unsure how to go about this,

I want to add unique identifiers for my users using WCF and when I go to add a GUID to my clients datacontext it throws this error

> Error 2
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Guid' to
>   'ServiceFairy.client' C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\PremLeague\ServiceFairy\Service1.svc.cs

Any chance you can help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ServiceFairy
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class     name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<match> GetAllMatches()
    {
        matchtableDataContext context = new matchtableDataContext();
        var matches = from m in context.matches orderby m.Date select m;
        return matches.Take(100).ToList();
    }

    public List<premtable> GetTable()
    {
        premContext context = new premContext();
        var table = from user in context.premtables orderby user.ID select   user;
        return table.Take(100).ToList();
    }

    public Dictionary<Guid, Uri> _clientUris = new Dictionary<Guid, Uri>();

    public void Subscribe(Guid clientID, string uri)
    {
        ClientsDBDataContext context = new ClientsDBDataContext();
        context.clients.Insert(clientID);           
    }
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with WCF?

Comment: Well for one its just the name of the service, and two, I created Linq to SQL object that contains my table for the clients, when I try to add a GUID to that table it throws that error, how is that unclear? and why downvote someone who is generally asking a question?

Comment: This isn't even a Linq or SQL issue, either.  Infact, this isn't related to *any* of the tags provided - this is nothing more than a simple case of providing the wrong object type - and the error message clearly says this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your Subscribe method at this line:

```
context.clients.Insert(clientID);   // error: clientID is the wrong type
```

You're passing `clientID` of type GUID to Insert() when instead you should be passing an object of type `ServiceFairy.client`.

It looks like you should be creating a new `client` object and saving that:

```
var client = new ServiceFairy.client() { ClientID = clientID };  // TODO: set other properties
context.clients.Insert(client);
```

As the TODO indicates, you should be setting other `client` properties too.

Comment: thanks for the help Keith I really appreciate this, I will work on it from this point forward, I knew there was an issue where I wasnt passing the right object, my original question before editing I wanted to know how to go about this problem

Comment: No problem John. Also make sure what you're doing with clientID is correct. It assumes the caller of Subscribe wants to set the clientID but typically these fields are autogenerated during Insert. Not sure what your design calls for.

Answer (score 2):

The error is as follows:

> Error 2
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Guid' to
>   'ServiceFairy.client'  C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\PremLeague\ServiceFairy\Service1.svc.cs 36  44 
>   ServiceFairy

Reading this, we have:

1. There is a problem with Argument 1. Checking the code at the line described, we can see that the first argument is 'clientId'.
2. The 'clientId' object is of type 'System.Guid'.
3. The first object needs to be of type 'ServiceFairy.client'.
4. The system is unable to magically convert a 'System.Guid' to a 'ServiceFairy.client'.

The solution, therefore, is to figure out yourself how to get a 'ServiceFairy.client' object instead.

Comment: thanks, I did understand the error just I didnt know how to go about it, I knew I couldnt pass GUID but rather than trying to explain what I was doing, showing the code was easier,